# KafkaStreams: forwarding only updated keys from Transformer

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

In my KafkaStreams app I have a registered local store (simple counters) that is updated in the `transform` method.

In the `punctuate` method I basically loop over the KV-store and push all the data to the output topic (so even if the value hasn't been updated).

One idea is to store the update timestamp for every key and forward only records updated since the last `punctuate` call.

But I think there should be a more convenient solution for that.

How to make this more performant and forward updated entries only?

Comment: The API does not provide better support for this -- your idea to store the timestamp in the value seems reasonable to em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments from Matthias, keeping track of updated the records is not supported at the moment.

Your approach of updating a timestamp in the value (or creating a "Value Wrapper" object that contains a timestamp you can modify)  and checking if an update has occurred since the last punctuate call is a valid approach.

-Bill